# matrix and vector multiplication python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to get my desired output for my code. The problem I am having is that when I multiply `matrix_0` and `vector_0` I get the correct output, but for `matrix_1` and `vector_1` it is incorrect. As well as `matrix_2` and `vector_2`. I am new to coding and the python3 language and don't understand why. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance. I have attached a link to my code. 
[code link](https://repl.it/@miguelBautista/PunctualGiantYottabyte)
The following is my code snipper

```
def matVec(matrix,vector):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(matrix)):
    total = 0    
    for j in range(len(vector)):
      total += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
    result.append(total)
  return result
matrix_0 = [[1, 2],[2, 3]]
vector_0 = [8, 10]
matrix_1 = [[ 2, 2, 3]]
vector_1 = [2]
matrix_2 = [[3, 2],[4, 4],[1, 1]]
vector_2 = [1, 2, 3]
print(matVec(matrix_0,vector_0))
```

Comment: Are the dimension requirements of matrix-vector multiplication met in the second and 3rd case? See this link https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/precalc-matrices/properties-of-matrix-multiplication/a/matrix-multiplication-dimensions

Comment: I believe so in the second case it's a 3x1 and 1x1. For the third case it's 2x3 and 3x1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In the second case you have `1*3` and `1*1`. In the 3rd case you have `3*2` and `1*3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an error or a wrong answer in _1 and _2. The reason for this problem is your matrixes and vectors can't be multipied. The amount of columns in the matrix has to be the same amount as the rows in the vector. Hope this helps, write a comment if there is something that needs a more thorough explanation.

Your code is really good

Answer (score 0):

The shapes of matrix_2 and vector_2 are not aligned. Test your code against what numpy outputs.

```
import numpy as np

np.matmul(matrix_2, vector_2)

Out[ ]: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-752f945775e1> in <module>()
----> 1 np.matmul(matrix_2, vector_2)

ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example?..my first input works its a 2x2 and a 2x1 it gives me the correct answer but using the same process for 2 and 3 doesn't do me any good l. Thank you you in advance

Comment: Your first is actually a 2x2 and a 1x2. The number of columns in the matrix has to be the same as the number of rows in the vector

Comment: Ok how would I write a 2x1 vector to make multiplication possible? Thank you in advance